# eclipse error: says build path is incomplete

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, weka

[image: Jars used in the project]Description   :

> Type The project was not built since its build path is incomplete.
>
> Cannot find the class file for weka.core.Instance.
>
> Fix the build path then try building this project.

It is not an android code, also do I need to post some code too. I think code is irrelevant for this error

Tried this solution:
Right click on project -> Properties -> Java Build Path (From Left List) -> Libraries (Tab) -> Add Library (Button on right) -> JRE System Library -> Next -> Workspace default JRE -> Finish

given in similar question on stackoverflow for Android Project - Didn't work.

Comment: Well what jar is `weka.core.Instance` in, and is it on the build path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says it all: there's a missing library in your class path. Try downloading the jar from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-stable/3.6.6) and add it to your class path. If you're using maven, gradle, etc., even simpler, just use the code provided in the previous link for each tool.

Answer (score 0):

It may have several reasons. Simplest of the solution is that

- Find out the `.m2` location for your Eclipse Maven (where jars are resolved) for mine case it is under `C:\Users\Awais Haider\.m2\repository` (issue lies here).
- Delete the repository section, once there is no other solution.
- Force update maven and its snapshot and clean the project.
- Once the updates and download of maven dependencies are completed, the error will be resolved.