# Eclipse Mars - The project was not built since its build path is incomplete

Tags: android, eclipse, build

I'm writing an Android application. I want to open it and run it but it is giving 1 error and 1 warning:

> The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot
>   find the class file for android.content.Context. Fix the build path
>   then try building this project The type android.content.Context cannot
>   be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class

How do I fix this?

Comment: add your log, then code, then reformat your post to be more readable

Comment: Please include the relevant code. Does the error refer to a line number or place where it arises?

Comment: [Checkout this link, hope it may help you out, as recently I have resolved this issued by following the solution, it usually occurs due to previously added build-path with eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46806124/3184239)

Comment: [Hope this one helps, the issue may exist due to build-path binding issue, may occur to change in eclipse version while having previous bindings of maven dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46806124/3184239)

Answer (score 0):

Reason of this problem is:

> It seems that you lack JDK (java.lang.Object comes from there )
>
> The problem is that you used the same Android API on different PC.
> Eclipse is lost with path names that are differents but with same API.
>
> To solve it, first re-select Android API version (set to another one
> and valid, then restore the on you want and validate it -> it will
> force Eclipse to reload API). Then go into project->properties-> java
> build path. Then remove "Unable to get system library for the project"
> then "Add library" and select "Android Classpath container".
>
> From: [The project was not built since its build path is incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341644/the-project-was-not-built-since-its-build-path-is-incomplete)

If above solution didn't work, follow these steps:

> 1. This issue is occurred only if the project shared between different machines.
> 2. For me I found java JDK is the problem.
> 3. My colleague used mac system and using jdk 1.7. but in my system I used jdk 1.6.
> 4. I guess that may be the issue. So I select project and open properties and change my jdk to 1.7
> 5. Change target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:19
> 6. Clean & Build
>
> Finally issue is fixed. I think this is because of If you build your
> project with higher JDK version thereafter you should build with same
> version.
>
> NOTE : we are not facing this issue before until my colleague build
> with JDK 1.7. After he started to using JDK 1.7 only this issue occur.
>
> Hope it will work for some one. And no need for install new eclipse.
>
> From: [The project was not built since its build path is incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341644/the-project-was-not-built-since-its-build-path-is-incomplete)

Check link above to find more solutions

Hope it helps